# Focus on current Screen Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to test the functionality of a developing webpage by using selenium in python.

This webpage have several instances where ids/names are repeated.

For example:

```
<input class="" name="title1" type="text">
```

This line of code is repeated but linked to different input fields throughout the code.

Therefore, when I try to test the webpage by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("elname").send_keys("BOb")
```

it seems to be looking for the first instance of the name that is in the code instead of focusing in on the current screen and inputting my desired input. This screen is not a window. So I can not switch to a window.

Is there a way to cause the driver to only focus on the current screen?

Comment: what you mean "current screen"?

Comment: The screen that I am typing information into. It is not a new window however it is a pop up screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "current screen" really a browser alert, or is it simply html that is designed to look like a dialog box in the browser window? It's it's really HTML, then these individual input elements probably have parents with a unique name.

```
<div id="first_dialog"><input class="" name="title1" type="text"></div>
```

so you would limit your search by that:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("first_dialog").find_element_by_name("elname").send_keys("BOb")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to interact with the current element in focus use `driver.switch_to.active_element`. This returns the current active element with which you can interact.